# Converting Bounding box regions into masks and saving them as PNG files

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I have a set of images with their bounding box values as shown below:

```
image_names class   xmin    xmax    ymin    ymax
image1.png  1       260     361     45      184
```

I wish to convert these bounding box values into a mask having the bounding box dimensions and filled with white pixels and store the masks for each image in the format "image1_mask.png" and so on. Do we have predefined functions to do this?

Comment: Just draw a white filled rectangle on a black background image from the two diagonally opposite corners (xmin,ymin) and (xmax,ymax). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9. For the black background, see Numpy np.zeros() or np.zeros_like(). https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image1.png') # read image
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),dtype=np.uint8) # initialize mask
mask[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax] = 255 # fill with white pixels
cv2.imwrite('image1_mask.png',mask) # save mask
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a blank image that is the same size as `image1.png`:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image1.png', -1)
mask = image.copy()
mask[:] = 0
```

Next, use [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9) to draw the white rectangle within the bounds of interest.  Thankfully it takes in a minimum and maximum horizontal and vertical coordinate that define the top left and bottom right limits of the rectangle.

```
num_channels = 1 if len(mask.shape) == 2 else mask.shape[2]
cv2.rectangle(mask, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), color=(255,) * num_channels)
```

`mask` will contain a white rectangle in the region of interest.  Take note that in the `cv2.rectangle` call, I've adapted this depending on whether the input image is grayscale or colour so you won't have to worry about doing any colour to grayscale conversion or vice versa.

Comment: `cv2.rectangle(.., thickness=-1)` should be added in case the rectangle must be filled